# Filter design graph

Tags: filter, graph

I've been trying for the last hour or so to remember the name of a graph or chart which can be used as a quick guide to calculate cutoff frequencies in filter circuits. I want to use it to show to some apprentices as part of a task but I cannot for the life of me remember what it is called.

It looks almost like a log graph, but it has R values, L values, C values and f values. You use it by selecting your R and L/C value, and following the lines in the graph untill they intersect. That point on the graph will tell you a frequency.

I have googled all sorts of things from filter calculator graphs, to old school filter design methods and gone through webpages, picture results and just cannot find it and I have racked my brain and cannot for the life of me recall the name of it. Can anyone remember the name of what I am thinking of?

Comment: I recall seeing something like this many years ago.  Unfortunately, I'm like you in that I can't think of appropriate search terms.  Good luck!

Comment: Did it look anything like a smith chart? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_chart)

Comment: @BeB00 kind of, but it was a normal rectangular chart. Would fit nicely on a bit of A4 paper

Comment: @DwayneReid I know, it's doing my head in that I can't recall the name!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a filter calculation nomograph. If you make a web search for filter nomograph, you'll find many of them.

Nomographs lost a great part of their usefulness when computers became available any time for anyone.

Comment: Fantastic!!! Thank you! I had a feeling it began with an 'n' but couldn't quite get there! It was the frequency/reactance nomograph in particular I was after, but thank you! That had been frustrating me for a long time!